# Add Throwing Range Potions

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering if you could make it so that you can throw potions further. I'm doing some grenades but have already used egg and snowball. I did not find anything else that is throwable. I have tried to search but did not find anything.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of [Double Speed Arrows](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/352928/double-speed-arrows), even though that question is newer, because it already has an answer that is correct in the newest versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible how you imagine it. You would have to completely reprogram how physics works in Minecraft, because there isn't just a "flight speed" parameter or similar.

Edit: This is possible since 1.13. See this answer for the same with arrows: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/352934/171580